# How to implement site-wide SSL leaving index.html alone using .htaccess?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, ssl

Currently I am using the following at the beginning of my root's .htaccess file.  Is there a safe way to exclude index.html?  Is this even necessary?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Everything on the site should be secured except the initial index.html page.  The site is a very simple service with one landing page, 3 registration pages (requiring ssl), and logged in mode (again requiring ssl).  Other than a few UI graphics, there is no major downloading of files.  The service is mostly textual once logged in.

The only reason I ask is that many threads on here suggest that having SSL enabled on the entire site is not a good idea.  It seems that since I only have one "landing page" and everything else needs to be secured, I may have the exception to this rule?  Any potential issues just leaving SSL for the index as well?

Thanks for any thoughts

Comment: You can add a `RewriteCond` testing `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}` to avoid the redirect. More information here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html Try something on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.html)?$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Perfect! Simple & effective